# Posterior distribution for a real sample

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian, posterior

I'm supposed to write a function in R that evaluates the posterior density, up to a multiplicative constant, at $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ for a logistic regression given a dataset $y$ and $X$. Where $y$ contains the results (pass/fail as TRUE/FALSE) and $X$ information about the participant (age, gender, private/public education). So I have $\boldsymbol{\pi}=\left(\pi_\text{intercept}, \pi_\text{age},  \pi_3,\pi_4 \right)$ where $\pi_3$ and $\pi_4$ are binary parameters (they can be either 1 or 0).

I want to write a function that calculates the posterior density (up to a multiplicative constant) assuming we have a vague prior $\boldsymbol{\pi} \sim N(\boldsymbol{0, I})$ where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the identity matrix.

So far I have tried writing code for
$$f(\boldsymbol{\pi}|x) \propto L(\boldsymbol{\pi})f(\boldsymbol{\pi})$$
where $L(\boldsymbol{\pi})$ is the likelihood function. I have come up with this so far

```
# R's build in logistic function    
logistic <- plogis

# Likelihood
L <- function(pi, y, X){
  p_vec <- as.vector(logistic(X %*% theta))
  resultat <- prod(p_vec**y*(1-p_vec)**(1-y))
  return(resultat)}

# prior function
prior <- function(X){
  return(dnorm(X, mean=0, sd=100)
}

posterior <- function(pi, y, X){
  likelihood <- L(pi, y, X)
  pr <- prior(X)
  return(pr*likelihood)
}
```

I know this is wrong since for the following data I should get

```
X <- cbind(1, 18:25, rep(c(0, 1), 4), rep(c(1, 1, 0, 0), 2))
y <- c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 4))
posterior(c(260, -10, 10, -20), y, X) / posterior(c(270, -15, 15, -25), y , X

## [1] 3.707556e+25
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code misses two `)` while `L` wants an unsupplied `theta`

Comment: And the first column of `X` is constant